# Is it possible to add single files to Windows 7 libraries?

Tags: windows-7, windows, libraries

I want to use libraries and the homegroup to share my files in an easy manner. However, i only want some files from folders (including the harddrive i've got, that has 100+ ER episodes in root and a bunch of other folders - i only want those ER series and nothing else) showing up in libraries, not the whole folders. There is a workaround for this when using libraries with windows explorer - you can use a saved search. However, if you want to access libraries remotely via different software (MediaBrowser, for instance), there is no way to use saved searches. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only add folders/directories to libraries.

Move the files into their own folder and add that to the library.

Moving a file within the same hard drive will take no time at all as you are simply updating the pointers that tell the OS where the file is. You aren't actually moving the file.

Comment: It will take no time, but would make libraries entirely useless for me, as i would still have to manually arrange the contents.

Comment: @Alex - It would take the same amount of time as selecting all the files and adding them to the library (if you could do that).

Comment: Yes, but this way i also have to rearrange where they currently sit (the described scenario is just an example, i actually have 4 hard drives with files all over)

Comment: @Alex - you need to add this information to your question. It's highly relevant that you have 4 hard drives of badly organised data.

Comment: It is not badly organised, i love the way it is organised. It is just not organised well for the purpose i now want to work with it. However, your suggestion pointed me in a different direction - the workaround for my problem is sharing all my drives, then creating links to the data i need, and then getting my software work with those links. While this is not as elegant as libraries and does expose all my data on the network, it still works.